# UICollectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind not called with Firebase UI dataSource

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, firebaseui

I am trying to add a header to a collection view bound to a firebase query with FirebaseUI.

I set up my collection view with a static frame for the collection header. (I have tried a collection view with a delegate call to `sizeForHeaderInSection` instead of the static frame set in the layout. The delegate method for `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` is not called regardless.):

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width), height: 100)
    let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    view.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(84, 0, 0, 0)
    view.register(VideoPollCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(VideoPollCollectionViewCell.self))
    view.register(PollCollectionViewHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(PollCollectionViewHeader.self))
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.delegate = self
    view.dataSource = self
    view.tag = VideoPollCollectionType.polls.rawValue
    return view
}()
```

Configure the dataSource in `viewDidLoad()`

```
    self.dataSource = self.collectionView.bind(to: self.videoPollQuery, populateCell: { (collectionView, indexPath, snap) -> UICollectionViewCell in
        let videoPoll = VideoPoll(with: snap)
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(VideoPollCollectionViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as? VideoPollCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
        cell.setPoll(with: videoPoll)
        return cell
    })
```

Add The datasource for FirebaseUI at the instance property level:

```
lazy var videoPollQuery: DatabaseQuery = {
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "/polls/")
    return ref.queryOrderedByKey()
}()

var dataSource: FUICollectionViewDataSource!
```

And add the delegate/datasource extension in the hopes that the method for loading a collection header view gets called

```
extension PollCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        guard let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(PollCollectionViewHeader.self), for: indexPath) as? PollCollectionViewHeader else { return UICollectionReusableView() }
        return view
    }
}
```

This produces a collection view with a empty header of the static frame size set in the layout of the collection view initializer or the sizeForHeaderInSection delegate method.

After adding a breakpoint within the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`, i was confused to discover this function is not being called.

Does anyone know the correct procedure to adding a subclass of `UICollectionReusableView` as a header to a collection view with a datasource from Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define height for supplementary view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.size.width, height:30)
}
```

Comment: Adding this does not cause the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` to be called.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue , any solution u discovered ? ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57208600/viewforsupplementaryelementofkind-is-not-getting-called )

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you initialize your CollectionVC the layout param is `UICollectionViewFlowLayout()` not `UICollectionViewLayout()` AND also that your collectionVC subclasses to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`